# Is there a safe way to delete a JointJS paper/graph

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I'm writing an app that makes use of JointJS to display diagrams.

However, I want to be able to dynamically add and remove diagrams from a page. Adding new diagrams is fairly trivial, but when I remove diagrams, is it safe to remove the DOM elements and let the graph and paper objects get garbage collected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's almost it. Better yet is to call `graph.clear()` (to remove all the cells from the graph and their associated views from the paper) and then `paper.remove()` (to cleanup the paper from the DOM, including its event handlers).

Comment: I am trying to delete/remove all the elements from the graph. When I do it as below, only links get removed and while removing other svg elements, it throws below exception:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unembed' of undefined

I tried to achieve it with graph.clear(); but because the above did not work I tried as below:

var cells = graph.getCells();
      for(i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
 graph.getCell(cells[i].id).remove();
    }


Both the ways I get this error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unembed' of undefined